# how to avoid concatenation in combo box

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to design a simple windows form application.Where if I select a combobox which represents countries. then again if i select any country then in another combobox states of that country will come.Finally if we select one state then corresponding cities will come in another combobox.First time if I do my operation it is working fine .. But second time if I'm doing any modification then it is concatenating.. 
here is my code-

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "INDIA")
    {
        string[] Country = { "Andhra Pradesh", 
       "Karnataka","Maharashtra"};
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(Country);            
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "USA")
    {
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Alabama", 
        "Alaska", "Arizona"});
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "CHAINA")
    {
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Beijing Municipality", 
        "Tianjin Municipality", "Hebei Province"});
    }        
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Andhra Pradesh")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Adilabad","Anantapur","Chittoor","Kakinada","Guntur","Hyderabad",            "Khammam","Kurnool","Medak","Nizamabad","Visakhapatnam","Warangal","Eluru"}); 
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Karnataka")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Bengaluru Urban", "Bengaluru Rural", "Chikkaballapur", "Kolar", "Mysuru" });
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Maharashtra")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Mumbai", "Pune", "Nagpur", "Thane", "Nashik" });
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Alabama")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Margaret","Helena","Southside","Mountain Brook","Vestavia Hills"});
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Alaska")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Anchorage", "Fairbanks", "Juneau", "Sitka", "Ketchikan" });
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Arizona")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Apache Junction", "Avondale", "Benson", "Buckeye", "Bullhead City" });
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Beijing Municipality")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Dongcheng", "Xicheng", "Chaoyang", "Fengtai ", "Miyun " });
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Tianjin Municipality")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Heping", "Hedong", "Xiqing", "Nankai", "Beichen" });
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Hebei Province")
    {
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Baoding‎", "Bazhou", "Chengde‎", "Handan‎", "Langfang‎" });
    }        
}
```

Please suggest me guys what should I modify in my code ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: nope brother  @xxbbcc

Comment: Make sure to clear you combo boxes before binding. Use comboBox2.Clear

Comment: @chikun If you haven't even taken the time and effort to debug your code, why do you expect people on SO to put time into finding a solution for you? Asking a question on SO requires showing a bare minimum of effort beyond posting your code and asking "I can haz answer?"

Comment: This is asp.net, not classic asp - I've changed the tags accordingly

Comment: @KevinWells next time I'll debug my code for sure .. Thank you for your suggestion .. The thing is I'm learning c# since 1month and new to this windows form application.:)

Comment: @John thank u  mate :)

Comment: @Moe the solution is posted below .. Yes I've already done it and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each time you select something from combobox1 (countries) or combobox2 (states) you want to "start over," you must first clear those secondary comboboxes on the appropriate events, such as:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combobox2.Items.Clear();
    combobox3.Items.Clear();
    . . .
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combobox3.Items.Clear();
    . . .
}
```

Also, it would be better to give your controls meaningful names. Rather than letting their keep their default generic names, give them names such as comboboxCountries, comboboxStates, comboBoxCities. This will make debugging easier.

Finally, it would be better to keep the list of places (countries, states and provinces, cities/towns) in a database or at least in some sort of separately maintained list. Putting them all willy-nilly in labyrinthine if blocks will end up making you go cross-eyed.

Comment: thanks a lot brother .. It solved my problem. Now I got it . This clear() function is clearing the list items.Thanks again.. your suggestion is highly appreciated .. Next time I will give user friendly names :)

Comment: @chikun If his answer is what you needed you should accept it (mark it with the check mark)

Comment: already accepted :) @KevinWells